# Converting method vb.net to python

Tags: python, vb.net, youtube, datasource

I am trying to remake vb.net code to python, the thing is that in vb.net when I scrape youtube I can get live count and other information from response doing the following:

```
Dim cookies As CookieCollection = Nothing

Dim data1 As String = req.[Get](String.Concat("https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=", _videoID), Nothing).ToString()
```

**but in Python I made this which shows different source code and Im not able to gather the same information like I did using vb.net:**

```
r = requests.Session()
r.cookies.set_policy(BlockCookies())

response = r.get("https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoID, headers = headers, proxies = proxies)
print(response.content) == response.text
```

I'm sure it is related to that cookiecollection from vb.net because the all code request headers etc...is same why should I get different source code of the response ?

Comment: The data is embed on the javascript code of the response. Can you share the current results with your vb.net and python codes?

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes I give up this and I trying now beautifulsoup seems like it works but pythin doesnt print all soup html with script but in breakpoint it shows so weird